# Get image from Clipboard in Silverlight/PInvoke

Tags: c#, silverlight, winapi, pinvoke, gdi+

So..... as titled.

Althought I was able to find a solution [here](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/discussions/273754).

But the solution is first writting the image into a temporary file and read it into stream.

So I have been trying to modify the solution, here is the cases I have been trying for **6 hours**...:

**Case 1)**

Read directly from stream instead using:

```
internal static extern int GdipSaveImageToStream(GpImage *image, IStream* stream, GDIPCONST CLSID* clsidEncoder, GDIPCONST EncoderParameters* encoderParams);
```

Which turns to:

```
[DllImport("gdiplus.dll", ExactSpelling=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern int GdipSaveImageToStream(IntPtr image, IntPtr stream, [In] ref Guid Encoder, IntPtr encoderParams);
```

I tried to pass in IntPtr.Zero into stream parameter, but the out result to the IntPtr is still zero... Fail...

**Case 2)**

Let's try... get the pixel data like one of the post said.

I know I can get HBITMAP by calling GetClipboardData:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetClipboardData(uint uFormat);
```

So let's try using GetBitMapBits, assuming I know the size of the image:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern int GetBitmapBits(IntPtr hbmp, int cbBuffer, [Out] byte[] lpvBits);
```

Now at least I can see data being copy, but GetBitMapBits is for 16-bit windows... Fail

**Case 3)**

Ok, so I should use GetDIBits to get the pixel data...

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern int GetDIBits(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr hbmp, uint uStartScan,
                                   uint cScanLines, [Out] byte[] lpvBits, ref BitmapInfo lpbmi, uint uUsage);
```

But now the problem is.... where I can get the device context for clipboard......

And more over, how do I even know about the Width and Height of the Clipboard Image.....

In WPF/WinForm we would have FromHBitmap method to do it easily.  I can't think of any other way other than writting into file and read it.  Or write a COM to solve this problem....

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of google, msdn and experiments...

I found out that I can actually get the BitmapInfo from hBitmap by using IntPtr.Zero..

```
hDC = User32.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
Gdi32.GetDIBits(hDC, hBitmap, 0, 1, null, ref bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

which will give me a BitmapInfo that contains Width, Height of the image.

Then now I could use the Width and Height to caculate the size of byte array that I will need, so now I can use:

```
//Similiarly, hMemDC is also a device context that created using IntPtr.Zero.
Gdi32.GetDIBits(hMemDC, hBitmap, 0, (uint)pixelHeight, binaryData, ref bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

There goes my binaryData, I can finally maps them to my WriteableBitmap with Height, Width, Byte[] :)

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the same goal. Any chance you could provide more details on your solution?